# Which type for Error in Axios in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-typings

I have the following working code:

```
                try {
                    self.loadingFrameMarkup = true;
                    const { data }: AxiosResponse<IMarkupFrameData> = yield axios.post<IMarkupFrameData>(
                        Endpoints.LoadMarkupFrame,
                        {
                            studyID: self.studyID,
                            frameIndex: frameIndex,
                        }
                    );

                    result = {
                        ...data,
                        layers: data.layers.filter((it) => it),
                    };
                    self.loadingFrameMarkup = false;
                } catch (error: AxiosError | Error) {
                    if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
                        self.state = QueueState.Unauthorized;
                    } else {
                        self.state = QueueState.Failure;
                    }
                }
```

typescript-eslint show error
Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if specified.ts(1196)
(alias) interface AxiosError<T = unknown, D = any>

What type should the error be in Axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to

```
    try {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err as AxiosError)
      // or
      // const error = err as AxiosError
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly give type definition of error in the catch block. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999#issuecomment-235796409).
Best solution would be giving type inside the catch block, as :

```
catch (err) {
       if ((error as AxiosError)?.response?.status === 401) {
             self.state = QueueState.Unauthorized;
           } else {
              self.state = QueueState.Failure;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The types in TypeScript only exist until the code is compiled. Once it's compiled, all you've got is typeless JavaScript.

Having type filters on catch clauses would require checking the errors' types at runtime, and there's simply no reliable way to do that, so simply assign it to `any` or `unknown` and then cast the error if applicable

```
catch (error: Error| any){
/// code
}
```

Comment: I don't try using any type

Comment: Only use it where there is no better thing to do it, using any is not recommended in typescript